# Unit Test an Event Listener is attaching/detaching an event to a class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, events, event-listener

I am stuck on one unit test, testing that an event was attached by an event listener to a class and detached. I cannot figure out how to do this and I have looked in many forums. The `EmailEventListener` attaches the event in the constructor to the `fakeClass` and detaches in the `Detach()` method. It also holds the method that is called when the event is fired. I am using FakeItEasy to create the fakeclass. Any thoughts? Thank you!

```
[TestMethod]
public void EmailEventListener_AttachedSubscription_ToClass_Successfully()
{
    EmailEventListener<ConcreteClass> realListener = new EmailEventListener<ConcreteClass>(fakeClass, A.Dummy<IEmailSender>());

    // Assert that fakeClass has the event

    realListener.Detach();

    // Assert that fakeClass does not have the event (probably in another test, but just wanted to show it here)

}
```

Comment: Don't test minor infrastructural things, test whether the class exposed desired behaviour when it comes to your *business logic*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assert that an event handler runs, have the handler that you attach do something that you can assert is done, say flipping a boolean `handlerExecuted` variable from `false` to `true`.

To assert that it is detached, do the same thing, but invert the assertion.  (Assert that `handlerExecuted` is `false` rather than `true`.)